# @csrf directive generates a validation error

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I use Laravel 10 and @csrf directive in my forms. I just noticed that this directive generates a w3C validation error:

> An “input” element with a “type” attribute whose value is “hidden”
> must not have an “autocomplete” attribute whose value is “on” or
> “off”.

Because it generates this HTML code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="aOZTBSeC6yErTEjpVskiG9c6YSaileoWLb6CGkrT" autocomplete="off">
```

I like to have pages with 0 errors (it might be useless). So, how can I no longer have this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually generate the CSRF token input without the autocomplete attribute. In your form, replace `@csrf` with...

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

This will generate a hidden input field without the autocomplete attribute, eliminating the validation error. Your form should look something like the following.

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('your.route.name') }}">
    <!-- other form fields go here -->
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can override the csrf_field function in your helpers.php file.

1. Create a `helpers.php` file in the root folder
2. in the `index.php` file before `require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';` add `require __DIR__.'/../helpers.php';`
3. now the `csrf_field` function will be overridden by your
4. use `@csrf` and render your code

```php
if (! function_exists('csrf_field')) {
    /**
     * Generate a CSRF token form field.
     */
    function csrf_field()
    {
        return '<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.csrf_token().'">';
    }
}
```